# I want to define where on hdd will .cs file going to be generated from a t4, programmaticaly

Tags: c#, t4

Okay, so everything is said in the title. I couldn't find anywhere on the web how to do this. I need this since we want to generate a .cs file elswhere, and not in the default destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve a similar task with the following technic.

Install the [T4 Toolbox](https://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/) extension to Visual Studio (probably not needed, I'm not sure).

Wrap your template content into a class like this:

```
<#+
public class MyTemplate : CSharpTemplate
{
    public MyTemplate ()
    {
    }

    public override string TransformText()
    {
        base.TransformText();       
#>
 // PUT YOUR TEMPLATE RENDERING HERE
<#+
    }
}
#>
```

Then create another template file and call this template explicitly. There you can configure the output parameters.

```
<#
    var mytemplate = new MyTemplate();
    mytemplate.Output.Project = @"MyProject.csproj";
    mytemplate.Output.File = @"MyFileRelativeToProjectFolder.cs";
    mytemplate.Render();    
#>
```

Please refer to [this article](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/03/t4-toolbox-generating-files-in-different-folders-and-projects/) for further details.